# Python: Why am I getting an "expected an indented block" on elif (r <= 9):

Tags: python, if-statement

I can't seem to figure out where I formatted this python code incorrectly. I've made sure that the indentions are correct, but I have no idea why this error is occurring. What am I missing here?

```
width = passageWidth(checkChamber, chamberMaxLength)
if (width >= 10):
    point = width/2
else:
    width = 2
r = random.randint(1, 19) #think aboout adding stairs later!!!
if (r <= 14):
    if (r == 5):
        door(False, 0) #continue 20, end door
    elif (r == 10):
        x = random.randint(1, 10)
        if (x == 1):
            door(False, -1) #continue 20, secret door
        else:
            #continue 20, dead end
    elif (r <= 9): ########### Error occurs here ##############
        if (r <= 6):
            if (r <= 2):
                #continue 30
            elif (r == 3):
                door(False, 0) #continue 30, door right at 20
            elif (r == 4):
                door(False, 0) #continue 30, door left at 20
            else:
        elif (r >= 6):
            if (r >= 8):
                passage(False, 0) #continue 30, passage left at 20
            else:
                passage(False, 0) #continue 30, passage right at 20
        else:
    elif (r <= 12):
        #continue 20 plus point, turn left, continue 10 plus point
    else:
        #continue 20 plus point, turn right, continue 10 plus point

    #offset edges along passage by point value to define sides of passage
elif (r <= 19):
    #create Chamber
else:
    #stairs

#Check if space is available, if not, terminate!
```

Comment: the `else` clause above it has nothing in it. you need something in it. use a `pass` if you don't want to code it

Comment: just adding to @MooingRawr answer. Same goes to all other "elif", "else" that are empty.

Comment: ok thanks. i didn't know about pass.

Answer (score 2):

```
    else:
        #continue 20, dead end
elif (r <= 9):########### Error occurs here ##############
```

Python doesn't allow empty blocks.  If you write

```
    else:
        pass # continue 20, dead end
elif (r <= 9):
```

the error should go away.  (To eliminate all such errors, you will need to do this in several places.)

Incidentally, Python preferred style is *not* to write parentheses around control expressions, unless you need them to split the condition over multiple lines.  That is, you should write

```
elif r <= 9:
```

Also, there should always be white space on both sides of the `#` introducing a comment.  The real Python parser doesn't care, but humans do, and "quick and dirty" parsers may also care (for instance, this is why the code in your question is not being syntax highlighted correctly).

Comment: also might wanna point out the other commented out blocks too

Comment: probably can just remove the `else` if its empty